# Mac equivalent application "shortcat"

Tags: gnome, scripting, x11, gui

There is a mac application called [Shortcat](http://shortcatapp.com/) and it make me envious.

For those of you averse to clicking links here is a summary:

> Keep your hands on the keyboard and boost your productivity! Shortcat is a keyboard tool for Mac OS X that lets you "click" buttons and control your apps with a few keystrokes. Think of it as Spotlight for the user interface.

So basically it lets you search within a GUI application. As I prefer typing for things than looking for things it sounds quite useful. I will probably be dreaming about this tonight.. and maybe looking for APIs to make it possible tomorrow. Unless of course...

there an equivelant available for gnome?

Comment: At least provide a summary of what it is.

Comment: most applications have shortcuts... and in kde many things have dbus actions... but honestly don't know.

Comment: IMHO, you might have better luck at Super User. (this comment prompted by http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/can-we-have-super-user-as-a-site-for-off-topic-close-reasons?noredirect=1#comment1915_1327)

Answer (score -1):

I've never heard of such an application for Gnome and I doubt there is one. In Linux and Unix everything can be done on the command line anyway, why would one go to the trouble of coding something like that?

In essence, the Gnome equivalent of Shortcat is `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I tend to use more applications than just the terminal, so something that searches through buttons and text, in other words makes the gui more terminal like, would be welcome.